# mathjax large font overlap

Tags: css, django, mathjax

I am displaying a list of items sometimes containing mathematical formulas, which I handle using MathJax. When the font is standard, there is no problem, but when I set the font-size of those items to large (in a class), I get an overlapping of some formulas with the text that follows them.
Is there a way of configuring MathJax to avoid this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide samples of the relevant code, and ideally a jsfiddle to show what the issue is?

Comment: You should also indicate the browser and OS you are using, and their versions.  Also, can you be clearer about what you mean by "setting the font to large"?  Are you simply zooming the browser, or are you changing the CSS in your file?  You may find that the [MathJax Forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mathjax-users) are a better place to get an answer to this question.